# React native how to call the function of component A from another component B which is included in Component A

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native i have a component A which has a function logout Now i have have included a component B in Component A and want to call the function logout of component A onPress.How i can achieve this.

```
class A extends component(){ 

      logout = () =>{ 
                 this.props.dispatch(logoutUser());
        }

        render(){ 
               return ( <View><B /></View>)
        }

}
```

Now in component B

```
class B extends component(){ 
        render(){ return(<View><MenuItem Onpress={this.logout} /></View>)}
 }
```

So i want when i click on Menuitem it call the logout function from Component A.Please ignore the any syntax this is just for the example.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass your function to B component through props

```
class A extends component() {

  logout = () => {
    this.props.dispatch(logoutUser());
  }

  render() {
    return (<View ><B logout={this.logout} /></View>)
  }

}

class B extends component() {
  render() { return (<View><MenuItem onPress={() => this.props.logout()} /></View>) }
}
```